# pbwmdrmc.dll not copied from Windows XP installation disc

Tags: windows-xp, dll

I installed Windows XP SP3 in my office system. During installation from CD, it showed

> pbwmdrmc.dll cannot be copied from the disc

I pressed skip, and installed. Now the applications and `cmd` can't be opened. Is there any way to resolve this other than reinstalling the OS?

I tried to download the file from the internet, but couldn't find it. Where do I have to copy this file to anyway?

Comment: That was the orginal sp3 cd, which has got some scratches due to mis handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your installation media and/or disc drive malfunctioned. Make sure that your media is clean. I would try a different disc. Is this a burnt copy or original? If burnt, it may have been a corrupted ISO or fault during copy.

Comment: Fault was with my cd

Comment: what I was looking for is to find a method to copy the missing dll file manually,which i could not found

Comment: Then I installed it using an another cd